# What do we call "being chosen by God as a prophet"?

Tags: single-word-requests

You're a **prophet**. You receive **revelations** from God. You have **miracles**. You bring a **religion**, possibly a **holy book**, and so on.

But what is the technical term to describe the moment you've been chosen by God as a prophet?

Comment: Your question is not clear. 1. You ask for 'a moment' but 2. You say 'bride'. A bride is not a moment.  Do you want the name of the event or the person or something else?

Comment: Are you looking for **election**, i.e. the choice by God of individuals, as for a particular work or for favor or salvation ?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, you took it so seriously that you couldn't even help a little bit. And I guess you're the one who donwvoted. The question is very clear. Look at the answer, and please, take the world a little easier.

Comment: No I didn't downvote. I asked for clarification. I still don't know what you are asking. Are you asking for a word equivalent to 'bride' or a word meaning 'choice by God'? It is the responsibility of the asker to be clear, not of answerers to guess.  However, since you apparently don't wish to be clearer I shall now vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: I see that you have edited your question and made it clearer. I shall now remove my vote to close.

Comment: In US Christian culture it would be "heard the call".  Someone who is into Old Testament terminology might call this "being anointed".

Comment: What @HotLicks said, *called* is pretty canonical for being chosen by God, though for the actual moment, perhaps *epiphany*, *revelation*, *visitation*?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a [Divine Call](http://phrasearch.com/Trans/Dean/Galatians/Gal-08.htm):

> - ***The word “call” comes from the Greek word kaleo [kalew] which means to call, to summon, to invite.***
> - Theologically the concept of the divine call has been broken down (not Scripturally but theologically) into two sub-categories: a general call, when we talk about the public proclamation of Scripture, when God through the Scriptures invites everyone to accept the free gift of Jesus Christ as their saviour—but that is not the subject we are talking about here; the more technical meaning of the divine call has to do with the ministry of God the Holy Spirit at the moment of salvation in making the gospel clear to the unbeliever so that they will respond by faith alone in Christ alone.

(phrasearch.com)

Comment: you understood what I'm looking for exactly. But I think *call* is not for THE moment of being chosen. In Persian we call it "بعثت".

Comment: Maybe *predestined*? Although some people do say they received [‘***a calling*** *from God*’](https://www.google.it/search?q=a+calling&oq=a+calling&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22a+calling+from+god%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: In Persian the term and the event is so clear that the day of Muhammad being chosen by God as the prophet of Islam is celebrated each year.